# Moving input values from one component on page to another component on another page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to React and working on a project where I want to move the input values from a form from one page to be displayed on another after submiting the inputs.

I have the below Measurement component with the input fields:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./measurements.scss";
import images from "../constants/images";
import { GrCircleInformation } from "react-icons/gr";
import Tooltip from "./Tooltip";
import MeasurementData from "./MeasurementData";

const Measurements = () => {
  const [toggleTooltip, setToggleTooltip] = useState(false);

  const [weight, setWeight] = useState();
  const [height, setHeight] = useState();
  const [shoulder, setShoulder] = useState();
  const [chest, setChest] = useState();
  const [abdominals, setAbdominals] = useState();
  const [hips, setHips] = useState();
  const [thigh, setThigh] = useState();
  const [calf, setCalf] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="app__measurements">
      <GrCircleInformation
        fontSize={16}
        onMouseEnter={() => setToggleTooltip(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setToggleTooltip(false)}
      />
      {toggleTooltip && (
        <Tooltip text="All measurements should be carried out while muscles are relaxes and be done in the exact same areas of the body every time. The time of day when the measurements are carried out should also be consistent" />
      )}
      <h2 className="app__measurements-heading">MEASUREMENTS</h2>
      <div className="app__measurements-data">
        <form className="app__measurements-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="weight">Weight (kg)</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="weight"
            value={weight}
            onChange={(e) => setWeight(e.target.value)}
            name="weight"
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="height">Height (cm)</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="height"
            value={height}
            onChange={(e) => setHeight(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="shoulder">Shoulders</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="shoulder"
            value={shoulder}
            onChange={(e) => setShoulder(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="chest">Chest</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="chest"
            value={chest}
            onChange={(e) => setChest(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="abdominal">Abdominals</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="abdominal"
            value={abdominals}
            onChange={(e) => setAbdominals(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="hips">Hips</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="hips"
            value={hips}
            onChange={(e) => setHips(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="thigh">Thighs</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="thigh"
            value={thigh}
            onChange={(e) => setThigh(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="calf">Calves</label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="number"
            id="calf"
            value={calf}
            onChange={(e) => setCalf(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit" className="app__measurements-btn">
            SAVE RESULTS
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <img src={images.success} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Measurements;
```

I then have the next page where I want the inputs to appear after submitting:

```
import React from "react";
import FitnessHeader from "../components/FitnessHeader";

import "./userPage.scss";
const UserPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <FitnessHeader />
      <div className="app__user">
        <div className="app__user-container">
          <h1 className="app__user-heading">YOUR PROGRESS</h1>
          <div className="app__user-content">
            <div className="app__user-measurements-container">
              <div className="app__user-section app__user-measurements">
                <h2 className="app__user-subheading">LAST MEASUREMENTS</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="app__user-section app__user-bmr">
                <h2 className="app__user-subheading">BMR RATINGS</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="app__user-section app__user-bmi">
                <h2 className="app__user-subheading">BMI RATINGS</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="app__user-results">
              <h2 className="app__user-subheading">PREVIOUS WORKOUT RESULTS</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserPage;
```

These two pages are connected in the App file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Fitness from "./pages/Fitness";
import UserPage from "./pages/UserPage";

function App() {


  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/fitness" element={<Fitness />} />
          <Route exact path="/user" element={<UserPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Unfortunately I don't really how to make these inputs appear on the UserPage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any kind of state management or context,

you are supposed to lift up the state by bringing the children component closer to the nearest parent component in this case App.js.

Define all the states in the App.js component then pass the state value as props in the respective components like below

```
import {useState} from react
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Fitness from '...'
import UserPage from '....'
 
function app(){
   const [weight, setWeight] = useState();
   const [height, setHeight] = useState();

  function submitData () =>{}
   
  return (
  <BrowserRouter >
   <Routes>
    <Route path='/' elements={<>home</>}
    <Route path='/form' elements={<Fitness 
      setWeight={setWeight}
      submitData={submitData}
     />}
    <Route pat='/user' elements={<UserPage 
      weight={weight}
      submitData={submitData}
    />}
   </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter >
)

}
```

in your components

```
export default function Fitness({ setWeight,submitData }){ use setWeight as required }

export default function UserPage({ weight }){ use weight as required }
```

you can read more about lifting up the state [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
Props drilling [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

I hope that helps.